# i have domain filter code for many2one field. how to do for many2many?

Tags: python, odoo

this is working fine for many2one field so i wanted **'area_id'** i.e **hindu_data_super** class should be in many2many or please let me know how can i select multiple item in one field...

```
class hindu_desh(osv.Model):
    _name="hindu.desh" 
    _description="Define districts" 
    _columns={ 'name':fields.char('District Name',size=64,required=True) }
hindu_desh()



class hindu_state(osv.Model): 
    _name="hindu.state" 
    _description="Define sub districts" 
    _columns={ 'name':fields.char('Sub District Name',size=64,required=True), 'hindu_state_id': fields.many2one('hindu.desh','District Name',select=True,required=True,ondelete="restrict") }
hindu_state()


class hindu_dist(osv.Model): 
    _name="hindu.dist" 
    _description="Define areas" 
    _columns={ 'name':fields.char('Area Name',size=64,required=True),
        #'area_type': fields.selection(area_type_lov,'Area Type',required=True), 
        'hindu_state_id':fields.many2one('hindu.state','Sub District Name',size=64,required=True),
           'district_id':fields.related('hindu_state_id','hindu_state_id',readonly=True,type='many2one',relation='hindu.desh',string='District Name'),
}

hindu_dist()



class hindu_data_super(osv.Model): 
    _name = "hindu.data.super" 
    _description = "Area of Registration Super"
    _columns = { 
        'district_id' : fields.many2one('hindu.desh','District', select=True, required=True, ondelete="restrict"), 
        'hindu_state_id' : fields.many2one('hindu.state', 'Sub District', domain="[('hindu_state_id', '=', district_id)]", select=True, required=True),
        'area_id' : fields.many2one('hindu.dist', 'Area', domain="[('hindu_state_id', '=', hindu_state_id)]", select=True, required=True),
    }
hindu_data_super()
```

Comment: You want many2many field in **hindu.data.super** instead of many2one ? want to set area_id many2many ? can you please add bit more description with what you want to do. So that somebody can give you better suggestion of solution of your problem.

Comment: ya hindu.data.super i have area_id that should be many2many field .becoz i wanted to select more than one item . so just that field should be in many2many field . i have tried . i am getting intigrity error . if you help to get many2many domain filter option it would be great

Answer (score 0):

I have changed structure of fields please check it and try it, and area_ids in hindu.data.super is fields.related so you will get all the areas according to state selection, if you need more than I think more work required for that.

```
class hindu_desh(osv.Model):
    _name="hindu.desh" 
    _description="Define districts" 
    _columns={ 'name':fields.char('District Name',size=64,required=True) }
hindu_desh()


class hindu_state(osv.Model): 
    _name="hindu.state" 
    _description="Define sub districts" 
    _columns={ 
            'name':fields.char('Sub District Name',size=64,required=True), 
            'hindu_state_id': fields.many2one('hindu.desh','District Name',select=True,required=True,ondelete="restrict") }
            'area_ids' : fields.one2many('hindu.dist','hindu_state_id','Areas')
hindu_state()


class hindu_dist(osv.Model): 
    _name="hindu.dist" 
    _description="Define areas" 
    _columns={ 
        'name':fields.char('Area Name',size=64,required=True),
        'hindu_state_id':fields.many2one('hindu.state','Sub District Name',size=64,required=True),
        'district_id':fields.related('hindu_state_id','hindu_state_id',readonly=True,type='many2one',relation='hindu.desh',string='District Name'),
}

hindu_dist()



class hindu_data_super(osv.Model): 
    _name = "hindu.data.super" 
    _description = "Area of Registration Super"
    _columns = { 
        'district_id' : fields.many2one('hindu.desh','District', select=True, required=True, ondelete="restrict"), 
        'hindu_state_id' : fields.many2one('hindu.state', 'Sub District', domain="[('hindu_state_id', '=', district_id)]", select=True, required=True),
        'area_ids' : fields.related('hindu_state_id','hindu_state_id',readonly=True,type='one2many',relation='hindu.dist',string='Area',store=True),
    }
hindu_data_super()
```

Comment: i am not able to select any item from area_id .. its showing creat and edit . . i dint ge how u have done area_ids[0][2] and wt is super_id,hindu_dist_rel

Comment: I think I need to understand your class structure and your aim as well, then I will update my answer.

Comment: please try to get me this one ... i badly need this for my acadamics project

Comment: see  i have situation like i have 2 **Banks** as Bank A and BankB two banks have created.** Bank A** has 4 ppl account A1,A2,A3,A4 when i select Bank A  the next field should filter only  A1,A2,A3,A4. and i have to select more than one accounts. that is possible by only @empiro many2manyfields .please drop just one code for that ....

Comment: You can not filter many2many like that you want because actually the logical relation between **hindu.data.super** and **hindu.dist** is many2one and one2many.

Comment: so wt can we do?. do we have any solution for this. or we can select item by any check box . i have tried its getting intigrity error